# How to hide a WCF Faulted state message box on an expected exception?

Tags: wcf, service, exception, messagebox

I have an application that supports multiple types of devices. One of the devices supported requires a WCF service to connect to it.

I have a thread that continuously checks for the service, and if it is found then it can proceed in calling necessary code to try to connect to the device... this all works fine if the service is running.

However, for the case where the service is not running, or not available (a user may not even use that device), a EndpointNotFoundException is getting thrown. I expect this exception to happen and I am catching it in a try/catch. However, I still get an error message pop up that says "The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state". How can I hide/disable this error box?

```
protected override void OnTimerCallback(object state)
{
    ServiceClient proxy = new ServiceClient("NetNamedPipeBinding_IService");

    try
    {
        proxy.Open();

        // do some stuff here...

        proxy.Close();
     }
     catch (EndpointNotFoundException)
     {
        // just ignore, expected if service isn't running
     }
     catch (CommunicationObjectFaultedException)
     {
        // just ignore, expected if service isn't running 
     }
}
```

I'm using .NET 3.5 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you googled this or searched SO?
I don't think a client channel in a faulted state will throw CommunicationObjectFaultedException when you try to use the proxy.  You would need to check if the client is in the faulted state.

Check the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763592/the-communication-object-system-servicemodel-channels-servicechannel-cannot-be)

Comment: Yes, I've googled it extensively... And I can get this error message to come up as soon as I start my application without even creating an instance of my client or making any service calls. (Basically the code I attached is commented out and the error message still appears when the service is not running)

Comment: And even if the client is in the faulted state, can't I just accept this as meaning that the service is not running (which is ok in some cases) and move on, but not have that annoying message keep popping up ? :)

Comment: I don't think I have enough information to speculate any further; if you are getting a messagebox popping up, without even creating an instance of the client or making service calls, it sounds like we aren't even close to understanding where that is coming from.  Your initial explanation makes more sense to me - where you first see the EndpointNotFoundException, then see the faulted channel. Are there other WCF services being connected to from other areas of code?  And is this an unhandled exception dialog box?

Comment: As for your second comment, you cannot take a faulted channel to mean the service is not running.  A channel can be faulted for other reasons.  Within the confines of your application, if you want to keep it simple, you can treat the situation the same way, but I have to refer you back to the link I provided - you'll want to check the "state" of the channel before using it (by channel I mean either proxy or client depending on which coding technique - in your case appears to be proxy)