# How to throw an exception that makes that channel in faulted state WCF

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, windows-services, faulted

I am using **netMsmqBinding**. The service goes to faulted state. It is hosted in windows service.

One reason i know is when there is an unhandled exception the service goes to faulted state.
My whole code is enclosed in **try catch** block. So my understanding is every exception will come come in catch and will be handled there.

We are getting an exception in our production environment. How can i create an exception that makes the channel in faulted state. Below is the screen shot of the trace
[trace detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnlub.png)

The exception came on a different thread and faulted the channel. Can this be a reason

Comment: Unless you are working in a framework that marshals exceptions between threads somehow, you can't catch an exception on thread X using a try/catch on thread Y

Comment: @Flydog57 can this be a reason..

Comment: Regarding capturing exceptions in the wcf service, you can take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763592/the-communication-object-system-servicemodel-channels-servicechannel-cannot-be